# How can i print selected checkboxes via php and also perform calculations?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to print all the checkboxes selected by the user of the array `items[]` in a table using PHP and also calculate the sum of the selected elements. Please see code below.

HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>four 100 watt light bulbs for $2.39</td>
  <td align="center">
    <input type="checkbox" name="items[]"  value='2.39'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>eight 100 watt light bulbs for $4.29</td>
  <td align="center">
    <input type="checkbox" name="items[]"  value='4.29'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>four 100 watt light bulbs for $3.95</td>
  <td align="center">
    <input type="checkbox" name="items[]"  value='3.9'/></td>
</tr>
```

PHP so far used for calculation:

```
$bulbs = array_sum($_POST['items']);
```

Please could you show me how I can print the selected checkboxes in a table using PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: it uses arrays so i thought java concepts could be used to solve

Comment: What do you want your bulb selection table to look like?

Comment: it should just print out Which item they had selected ie the value and name of each selection.

Comment: see possible answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (not sure it will work, I didn't test):

```
    foreach ($_POST['items'] as $item)   {
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <?php echo $item; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
```

However if you are getting these values from a database (which would make more sense), it would also be a lot easier to both handle any calculations in the SQL and get the rest of your data from the database.